# Spring default bean candidate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I'm writing a library that uses spring, for others to use. In my library, I have class `A` that has an interface `B` as a field (with `@Autowired`).
I have a default implementation of that field, but the user can implement a custom implementation by himself. What I want to happen is the following:
If the user implemented `B`, I want that bean to be injected to `A`, otherwise I want my default implementation to be injected.
Something like the opposite of `@Primary`

I know that the user can add the `@Primary` annotation in order for that to happen, but I don't want him to add any other annotation besides `@Component` (because it is not clear for the user why he must add the `@Primary` annotation)

Is there a way to achieve this behavior? I've also tried `@Order` and `@Priority`, but no luck - the user must add another annotation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should create [your own auto configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration). Auto configuration classes are always processed last so user's own configuration is processed first and when using `@Conditional...` annotations user's beans will take precedence.

Your auto configuration class should look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAutoConfiguration {

  @ConditionalOnMissingBean(B.class)
  @Bean
  public B defaultImplementation() { return A(); }

  @Bean
  public UsesB classThatUsesB(B b) { return UsesB(b); }

}
```

In this case if the user of your library defines a bean of type `B` it will always be used first and if they don't the bean created by the `defaultImplementation` method will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. Spring's *@Autowired* is rather specific. Making it perform differently without any configuration changes (either to XML or the Spring configuration class) is pretty much impossible.